# How do I convert a pandas index of epoch time to regular time?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe with an index in epoch time, and a price like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1547942400000, 1548028800000, 1548115200000], 'Price': [1170, 1170, 1170]})

# EDIT the index column in unnamed.
```

I have tried directly editing the index like

```
df.index = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(df.index) / 100).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# 100 to make it this year vs 1970s or 2040s
```

I have also tried using apply() which can not be used on an index.
I am thoroughly confused and frustrated. I would think pandas would make such a thing trivial.

Any help is appreciated as I hope to run a super simple autocorrelation on it and see what I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below snippet

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1547942400000, 1548028800000, 1548115200000], 'Price': [1170, 1170, 1170]})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Index'],unit='ms')
df
    Index   Price
Index       
2019-01-20  1547942400000   1170
2019-01-21  1548028800000   1170
2019-01-22  1548115200000   1170
```

Comment: I changed ```df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Index'],unit='ms')``` to use df.index instead of df['Index'] since it was not named. Thanks for the answer!